# Where can I download a map of the world for kids

Tags: cartography

I would like to download and plot some kind of fun (large) illustrated map of the world or Canada (with animals/ dinosaurs / points of interest, etc.) for my son's preschool cartography class. Anyone has a good link or map they can share?

Comment: Not really pre-school but for reference a little later http://mapperz.blogspot.com/2008/08/free-maps-for-education-in-pdf-format.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

National Geographic is well known

**Xpeditions**

Canada
http://www.nationalgeographic.com/xpeditions/atlas/index.html?Parent=canada&Rootmap=&Mode=d&SubMode=w

[image]

World
http://www.nationalgeographic.com/xpeditions/atlas/index.html?Parent=world&Rootmap=&Mode=d&SubMode=w

[image]

(Please note I have worked via sub-contract for National Geographical Society in the past)

The idea is for children to colour them in.

Terms of Use are favourable for Education (Class Work)
http://www.nationalgeographic.com/community/terms/#eduuse

Answer (score 4):

[CIA factbook](https://www.cia.gov/kids-page/index.html)

[kids geo is another great source](http://www.kidsgeo.com/geography-games/united-states-america-map-game.php)

Also get your school to start the nat geo [geography bee.](http://www.nationalgeographic.com/geobee/)

I have had kids place at state the past two years, lots of fun!

Here are some learning teaching links that might help.
[order dinosaurs facts and fiction](http://store.usgs.gov/b2c_usgs/catalog/setCurrentItem/%28isQuery=yes&xcm=r3standardpitrex_prd&query=*dinosaur*&layout=6_1_61_62_2&uiarea=2&page=2&itemPageSize=5&ctype=areaDetails&next=seeItem&carea=0000000039&citem=00000000070000000005%29/.do)  Tried to order myself. (free) but link doesn't seem to work.

[image: store]
[USGS4](http://store.usgs.gov/b2c_usgs/b2c/display/%28xcm=r3standardpitrex_prd&layout=6_1_61_50_2&uiarea=2&ctype=areaDetails&carea=0000000347%29/.do)
[USGS1](http://egsc.usgs.gov/isb/pubs/teachers-packets/mapadventures/malessn5.html)
[Enchanted learning](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/Home.html)
[USGS2 gip](http://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/dinosaurs/)
[Wow lots of links!](http://wasdpa.org/schools/hooverville/WebSites/Teachers/teachers.htm)
[Links for preK-12](http://www.internet4classrooms.com/earthspace.htm)
[Education USGS 3](http://education.usgs.gov/)
[USGS 5 Dinosaur NM](http://www.nature.nps.gov/geology/inventory/publications/map_graphics/dino_geology-layout.pdf)
[More USGS](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2002/of02-370/omeara.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Copyright and reprinting rights** might be an issue with the national geographic image above in class room use.

**Wikipedia** has some free ones with open licenses: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_map

You could also use **Open Street Map** which has reproduction friendly licenses with attribution.
Cloud Made has a nice style editor where you could make Open Street Map look "coloring friendly" http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor

Comment: No Copyright issues with Educational Maps from National Geographic - See Educational Terms of Use - http://www.nationalgeographic.com/community/terms/#eduuse

Comment: Great find.  I am pleasantly surprised.